# Is there a way to find out a player's name using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make map where if you die, it says in the chat that the player in question has died. For example, if a guy named BlehBlehBleh died, it would say in the chat, "BlehBlehBleh has died!" or something like that. 
P.S I think it has something to do with scoreboards.

Answer (score 2):

Using selectors, you can easily say BlehBlehBleh died!
With the say command

`/say @a[deaths=1] has died!`
That will say any player with the score deaths = 1 has died. Then you would set his deaths to 0 to avoid a loop :) Also, detect IF a player has died first before doing the command.
So order of the commands:

`scoreboard players test @a deaths 1`

Then

`say @a[deaths=1] has died!`

`scoreboard players set @a[deaths=1] deaths 0`

So you would be right thinking its about scoreboards.

Edit: To store someones name in a scoreboard just make an objective then type this in

`scoreboard players set @a objectiveName 0`
That would make the score of every player set to 0. To add a deathcount just do
`scoreboard objectives set deaths deathCount` I believe